# MyLocationListener implements LocationListener - removeUpdates doesnt work

Tags: android, locationlistener

I want to put a LocationListener in a seperate class like this:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

it works, but when i trigger:

```
        locationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
```

with mListener as MyLocationListener object, it just doesnt remove the registered updates. onLocationChanged gets called on and on and on......

Any help?

Comment: Where is `removeUpdates` called?

Comment: thank you Salem, i just figured it out. removeUpdates wasnt called because of some conditions ;) thanks anyway!

Comment: i also did: "LocationManager locationManager=this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));" to get the location manager at different methods, assuming that it returns always the same reference to the LocationManager. That doesnt seem to be true and leads to cause this. so the LocationManager has to be exactly the same instance always.